# How to print undeclared variable when using bison

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have made a parser using Bison on Ubuntu.

The parser is checking the syntax  successfully,
but I couldn't print a token in an incorrect position or for an undeclared variable, because my lex file just passes the token according to the regex that I made.

For example:

I had made regex for Identifier including a keywords list.
When the  scanner found a matched token, the scanner returned the token to the parser. In the yacc file, it can be given a token which scanner passed to the parser.

In the scanner, there is no regex for incorrect symbol (for example, in `ints val=1;` the use of `ints` is incorrect; the scanner just passed that string).

So the incorrect symbol couldn't be passed to the parser.

I had made Parser checking whether input source code is correct or not,
but it can't print an incorrect symbol (or undeclared variable).

Is there any function or parameter that I can use?

Comment: You need a symbol table, and you'll record the valid identifiers in the symbol table, and the semantic actions in (or called from) your parser (Bison) code will validate that the identifier returned is a known (valid) identifier, reporting an appropriate error if it is not known — and, if possible, avoiding re-reporting that the same identifier is not valid thereafter until the end of a suitable scope.

Comment: Is symbol table in lex code and semantic actions in yacc code ?
i made symbol table in lex code and record the vaild Identifier.but bison couldn't recognized token given by flex. because my lex is just passing valid Identifier...

Comment: It recognises the identifier. Whether it's a declared identifier s a semantic action, not a parsing action. See the duplicate that @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 suggested, and his answer there.